# Cucumber JVM retry with selective output

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

We implemented a retry mechanism for failing scenarios based on this article:

http://mkolisnyk.blogspot.ro/2015/05/cucumber-jvm-junit-re-run-failed-tests.html

Everything is working fine. But the problem is that the output gets polluted with the all retries. I want to have only the output of the last scenario.

How can I block the output of all scenarios except the last one?

Comment: What do you mean by output? Console output? Or output in reports, i.e. you have retriesAmount of tests in your report?

Comment: The output/report în tests. We are are sending the xml report in the next step in our delivery pipeline. So if there are tests that are failing the build deployment will fail also.

Comment: I had similar problem, however the only solution I was able to find is to clean reports afterwards, e.g. in json format it's pretty easy: you just need to delete all root nodes except last one. You may want to add @After method, shutdown hook or custom app that would do it after test execution was completed and before sending those reports any further.

Comment: Yes, I think this is one way to do it. Although I don't fill very comfortable to modify the reports. I tried to extend JunitReporter but that didn't work. I found out that cucumber is to coupled to Junit. We are using xml for the report. If we will do it that way and it's working I will come back and wrote a more technical answer. Thanks Mikhail.